# How to Properly Write User Defined Function in PHP?

Tags: php, function

I have a php file named priceAPI.php that gives me price of gold in difference currencies.  For example $price_usd is for price in US Dollar and likewise $price_aed is for price in UAE Dirhams and so on.
I am trying to write a function that based on a string defined by a user would fetch the price that relates to user's choice of currency:

My function looks like this:

```
function getPrice($user_currency) {
require_once('priceAPI.php');
if($user_currency == 'usd') {

$price = $price_usd;
return $price;

}elseif ($user_currency == 'aed'){
$price = $price_usd;
return $price;

}

$user_currency = 'aed';

echo getPrice($user_currency);
```

When I try to call the function it doesn't give any results whereas if I echo $price_usd or $price_aed it does give me the price.

Any help as to how I can make this function work will be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: are you sure you have `$price_usd` defined in priceApi.php?

Comment: @ daremachine  yes very sure as it echo's it out when i print it outside the function.

Comment: Thank you all those who tried to help.  I was calling the file priceAPI.php twice within the same script which was not working somehow.  Removing require call to the file in the beginning of the script did the trick. Thanks @daremachine